# not able to resolve dependancy conflict while creating aws resources using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I was trying to create below AWS resources, primarily what I am trying to do is, create an ec2 instance, EIP, and attach an EIP to the AWS instance and then using provisioners I would like to execute few commands over the instance using ssh connectivity

The challenge here is, terraform script fails with an error as below

```
$ terraform apply -auto-approve

Error: Invalid expression

  on ec2-resource.tf line 16, in resource "aws_instance" "iac-ec2":
  16:   depends_on    = aws_eip_association.eip_assoc.allocation_id

A static list expression is required.
```

I tried 5-6 differnt ways, in one more approach, in order to ensure, epi gets attached to ec2 instance.
But as we have a dependency requirement to have eip attached to the ec2 before we ssh using public IP (from eip), the connection fails with timeout error after creating resources partially, which means it created ec2 but before attaching eip to the ec2, it is trying to connect with ec2, and fails with a timeout

error:

```
aws_subnet.iac-subnet1: Creating...
aws_security_group.iac_security_group: Creating...
aws_subnet.iac-subnet1: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-0b3e3bb02f60e2993]
aws_instance.iac-ec2: Creating...
aws_internet_gateway.iac_igw: Creation complete after 2s [id=igw-06a40dd6622632c07]
aws_route_table.iac_route_table: Creating...
aws_route_table.iac_route_table: Creation complete after 1s [id=rtb-03051d67fbd61af2c]
aws_main_route_table_association.iac_aws_main_route_table_association: Creating...
aws_route_table_association.iac_subnet_route_table_association: Creating...
aws_security_group.iac_security_group: Creation complete after 3s [id=sg-09a243e7b3247a257]
aws_route_table_association.iac_subnet_route_table_association: Creation complete after 0s [id=rtbassoc-0e8d77a6cb8e36855]
aws_main_route_table_association.iac_aws_main_route_table_association: Creation complete after 1s [id=rtbassoc-06a32196916bc6b55]
time_sleep.wait_300_seconds: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_instance.iac-ec2: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
time_sleep.wait_300_seconds: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
aws_instance.iac-ec2: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
time_sleep.wait_300_seconds: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
aws_instance.iac-ec2: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
time_sleep.wait_300_seconds: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
aws_instance.iac-ec2: Provisioning with 'remote-exec'...
.
.
.
.
aws_instance.iac-ec2 (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
aws_instance.iac-ec2 (remote-exec):   Host: <public-ip>
aws_instance.iac-ec2 (remote-exec):   User: ec2_user
aws_instance.iac-ec2 (remote-exec):   Password: false
aws_instance.iac-ec2 (remote-exec):   Private key: true
aws_instance.iac-ec2 (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
aws_instance.iac-ec2 (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
aws_instance.iac-ec2 (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
aws_instance.iac-ec2 (remote-exec):   Target Platform: unix
aws_instance.iac-ec2: Still creating... [7m1s elapsed]
aws_instance.iac-ec2: Still creating... [7m11s elapsed]
aws_instance.iac-ec2: Still creating... [7m21s elapsed]
aws_instance.iac-ec2: Still creating... [7m31s elapsed]


Error: timeout - last error: dial tcp <public-ip>:22: i/o timeout
```

Below is the code block

```
resource "aws_instance" "iac-ec2" {
  ami           = var.var_ami # ap-south-1
  instance_type = var.var_instance_type[0]
  key_name      = "terraform-singapore"
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.iac-subnet1.id
  #depends_on    = aws_eip_association.eip_assoc-eip.association_id
  tags = {
    Name = "Iac-EC2"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y nginx1.12",
      "sudo systemctl start nginx"
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ec2_user"
      private_key = file("./terraform-singapore.pem")
      host        = aws_eip.iac-eip.public_ip
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "iac-eip" {
  vpc        = true
  #instance = aws_instance.iac-ec2.id
  tags = {
    Name = "IaC-EIP"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {
  instance_id   = aws_instance.iac-ec2.id
  allocation_id = aws_eip.iac-eip.id
}

resource "aws_vpc" "iac-vpc" {
  cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr
  tags = {
    Name = "IaC-VPC"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "iac-subnet1" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.iac-vpc.id
  cidr_block = var.subnet1_cidr
  depends_on = [aws_vpc.iac-vpc]
  tags = {
    Name = "IaC-Subnet1"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "iac_security_group" {
  name        = "iac_security_group"
  description = "Allow HTTP and SSH traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.iac-vpc.id
  ingress {
    description = "ALLOW SSH TRAFFIC"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    description = "ALLOW HTTP TRAFFIC"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "iac_security_group"
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "iac_igw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.iac-vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name = "IaC-IGW"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "iac_route_table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.iac-vpc.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.iac_igw.id
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "IaC_RouteTable"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "iac_subnet_route_table_association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.iac-subnet1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.iac_route_table.id
}

resource "aws_network_interface_sg_attachment" "iac_sg_attachment" {
  security_group_id    = aws_security_group.iac_security_group.id
  network_interface_id = aws_instance.iac-ec2.primary_network_interface_id
}

resource "aws_main_route_table_association" "iac_aws_main_route_table_association" {
  vpc_id         = aws_vpc.iac-vpc.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.iac_route_table.id
}
```

My aim is to create an ec2 instance, attach eip, and using provisioners block run the command on the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two apparent issues in your code:

1. **Wrong username**. It should be `ec2-user`, not `ec2_user`.
2. **Wrong place for your provisioner**. In your case you should use `user_data`, but for the sake of it, if you really want to use provisioner, then it must be external (remove from the instance) to the instance and use `null_resource`:

```
resource "aws_instance" "iac-ec2" {
  ami           = var.var_ami # ap-south-1
  instance_type = var.var_instance_type[0]
  key_name      = "terraform-singapore"
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.iac-subnet1.id
  tags = {
    Name = "Iac-EC2"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "myprovisioner" {

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y nginx1.12",
      "sudo systemctl start nginx"
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ec2-user"
      private_key = file("./terraform-singapore.pem")
      host        = aws_eip.iac-eip.public_ip
    }
  }
  
  depends_on = [aws_network_interface_sg_attachment.iac_sg_attachment]
}
```